# Swift - Updating Tableview after saving Core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I have a mainVC where i perform a fetch request.
I then pass the fetched data to a second view controller (HomeVc) and then to  third (MyparamsVc)
In the third VC i have a tableView Which list all the parameters which have a relation one-to-may with the entity i fetched in the main VC

In a fourth View controller i add the new parameters through a form (addParamVC). After saving i dismiss the controller and pop the previous one (MyparamsVc).
My problem is that the tableview is not updating with the new data unless i go back to my HomeVC and then again into the MyparamsVC

I have implemented the func controllerDidChange an Object but since i'm not performing the fetch in the same controller the function is never called... How can i Update the tableview with new data?

MainVc fetchRequest:

```
 var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<SwimminPool>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    attemptFetch()

}
func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwimminPool> = SwimminPool.fetchRequest()
    let dataSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "poolCreatedAt", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dataSort]


     let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }

}
```

addParamVC saving func:

```
var swimmingPoolToConnect: SwimmingPool!
var parameterToEdit: Parameter?

@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    var parameter: Parameter

    if parameterToEdit == nil {
        parameter = Parameter(context:context)
    } else {
        parameter = parameterToEdit!
    }

    if let pH = phTextField.text?.characters.split(separator: ",").joined(separator: ".") {
        if let pHnoComma =  Double(String(pH)) {
        parameter.paramPH = pHnoComma
        }
    }
  parameter.createdAt = Date()

    swimmingPoolToConnect.addToParameters(parameter)

    ad.saveContext()
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

MyparamsVC:

```
 var parameters = [Parameter]()
var swimmingPool: SwimmingPool! {
    didSet {
        parameters = (swimmingPool.parameters?.allObjects as! [Parameter]).sorted(by: {$0.createdAt! > $1.createdAt!})
    }
}

var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Parameter>?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParamCell", for: indexPath) as! ParamCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

 func configureCell(cell: ParamCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let param = parameters[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(parameter: param)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let  parameterToPass = parameters[indexPath.row]
        DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyParameterDetail", sender: parameterToPass)
        }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return parameters.count
   }
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

  //Never enter these func

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type){
    case.insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }

    case.delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

    case.update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ParamCell
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        }

    case.move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a reference to the presenting view controller add the item to the `parameters` array and insert a row in `MyparamsVC` from `addParamVC`

```
ad.saveContext()
let paramsVC = self.presentingViewController as! MyparamsVC
let lastRow = paramsVC.parameters.count
paramsVC.parameters.append(parameter)
paramsVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: lastRow, section: 0)], with: .none)
paramsVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or even in the completion handler of the `dismiss` method

```
ad.saveContext()
let paramsVC = self.presentingViewController as! MyparamsVC

paramsVC.dismiss(animated: true) {
    let lastRow = paramsVC.parameters.count
    paramsVC.parameters.append(parameter)
    paramsVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: lastRow, section: 0)], with: .none)
}
```

Comment: Can't believe you saved me once again... it's since two days that i was trying to achieve this....instead of lastRow can i insert it as first element?

Comment: Yes, instead append `insert(parameter, at:0)` and `IndexPath(row:0, section:0)`

Comment: I owe you big time!!! thanks to you i've finished the part that worried me the most and everything works perfectly!! thanks! in the last days...u did save me! :)

Comment: You're welcome. When displaying CoreData in a table view without a helper like `NSFetchedResultsController` you have to manage three things simultaneously: The Core Data stack, the data source array and the user interface (table view).

Comment: i started coding in swift two months ago.... so totally new... :) thx to your help i learnt a lot which is great! :) i'll make treasure of all these pieces of advise

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh view controller after save to core data like

```
 self.viewDidLoad()
  self.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Or You can reload tableview like

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: You have fetched data in mainvc but you save data third vc and want to see in MyparamsVC. Right

Comment: i fetch the swimmingpool in mainVC and then pass it to the myparamsVC. myparamsVC has a segue to AddParamVC where i save the parameter. Once saved i display them in myparamsVC

Comment: after save you can append to parameters

Comment: in AddParamVC u mean?

Comment: sorry but im new to swift.... i don't have an array of parameter in AddparamVC....i just assign the value from the textfield and save them. var parameter: Parameter----> parameter.paramPH = pHnoComma.....

Comment: You can fetch your data to myparamsVC or you can use strut  for array assign value to array and then you can append  to it  bellow like----class StaticOperation {
    
    struct glovalVariable {
       
        var staticparameters = [Parameter]()
}
}

Comment: i did perform fetch in myparamsVC but i get this: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)